# VBA fails on first try error 5479

Tags: vba, ms-word

It seems like [this guy](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.word.application.errors/RXeTEiRDZP4) has had the same problem as me, but the vbModeless doesn't seem to do the trick.

I'm creating a simple add-in, and I want VBA to open a word file, copy the entire content and paste it in the original document.

It works perfectly when executed from the VBA editor or even after the first run where it debugs, but opening a Word instance for the first time and trying to execute the code from the add-in seems to be a problem.

The code is as follows:

```
Sub insertFigureFrame(control As IRibbonControl)
 StandardFrames.StartUpPosition = 0
 StandardFrames.Top = Application.Top + (Application.Height - StandardFrames.Height) * 0.5
 StandardFrames.Left = Application.Left + (Application.Width - StandardFrames.Width) * 0.5
 StandardFrames.Show
End Sub

Sub Standard()

Dim OriginalDocument As String
Dim SaveChanges As Boolean
Dim doc As Document

On Error GoTo err:
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


OriginalDocument = ActiveDocument.Path
Documents.Open MyTemplate

Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Copy
Documents("MyTemplate").Close (SaveChanges = False)

Documents.Open (OriginalDocument)
Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault

Exit Sub
err:
Call errHandling

End Sub
```

The StandardFrames Userform calls the sub Standard.

Any idea what might cause the problem?

EDIT:

I'm using Word 2007 and Windows XP.

Comment: To clarify, your problem is the same as the one given in the link, right? It's Runtime error 5479 when you execute your code?

Comment: Exactly. Sorry for being unclear!

Answer (score 0):

Try hidding your userform before you open a document:

```
Sub Standard()
StandardFrames.Hide
'The rest of your code
End Sub
```